# Is $e^{ix}$ just the name of a point on the unit circle?

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

Am I right to say that $e^{ix}$, where $x$ is the angle in a unit circle, is just the name of a point on the unit circle corresponding with some angle?

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not just "a" point corresponding to "some" angle ... it's **the** point corresponding to **that** angle, $x$.

Comment: Personally, I'd say that $e^{ix}$ is "just the name" of the complex number $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{ix}{1!}+\frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\cdots+ \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "just the name"? In my mind, $e^{ix}$ is what you get when you plug $ix$ into the Taylor series for $e^z$. It is true that this turns out to be a point on the unit circle, but that is not obvious in advance.

Comment: I tried mapping the unit circle a cartesian coordinate system and found that really the imagination term was invented to identify a section of base 10 number system and the the real term identifies the term within that section

Comment: It is just a name i think, but the object is mapped to 2 properties, angular frequency and time

Comment: So really the term is just a symbol which identifies a number within a section

Comment: @littleO and do you know how the Taylor series was invented?
Or

Comment: Or do you only know whats its for and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in saying that, in the Argand plane, the point corresponding to the complex number $e^{i\theta}$ certainly does lie on the unit circle (centered at the origin) at angle $\theta$ from the $x$-axis, measured anticlockwise.

However, it's not the name of any point or anything in any plane other than the Argand one. And even though it is the name of the point on the Argand plane, it's not "just" that point. It also happens to be a complex number, and as such you can do a lot of cool mathematics with it.

Comment: A.k.a. the Gauss-Argand plane.

Comment: Why were complex number invented may i ask? And what was the process on invention?

Comment: e is the name given to some quantity, like that of 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Things like complex number are just names given to something. How was this something invented or discovered?

Comment: I can assign delboy =  e*pi^2 
But what is the significance of e*pi^2

Comment: Thats what im trying to say

Comment: arguably mathematics wasn't "invented" but discovered; it's just a natural consequence of mathematics i guess. i mean i can see why people would disagree with the 'natural' part. unfortunately this delboy stuff isn't very natural. It's fairly obviously you made that one up on the spot without much foresight, without practical considerations, or anything like that. Feel free to google around for practical and theoretical applications of complex numbers if you want

Comment: The symbols were invented to create order, since the tendency of the universe to increase in disorder. Though i agree that mathematics can be discovered

Comment: Because symbols were initially representative of the naturally occurring relations from observation